# How to get website title from Delphi?

Tags: delphi

i don't want to use twebbrowser, 
anyone know other metod for getting the title of a website?

Answer (score 12):

You can get the content of the webpage using the [`InternetOpenUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`InternetReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions and then seek for the `<title>` tag.

check this sample app.

program GetTitleHTML;

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  WinInet,
  StrUtils,
  SysUtils;

function GetHTMLTitle(const Url:string):string;
const
BuffSize     = 64*1024;
TitleTagBegin='<title>';
TitleTagEnd  ='</title>';
var
  hInter   : HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  Buffer   : Pointer;
  i,f      : Integer;
begin
  Result:='';
  hInter := InternetOpen('', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if Assigned(hInter) then
  begin
    GetMem(Buffer,BuffSize);
    try
       UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(hInter, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,0);
       try
        if Assigned(UrlHandle) then
        begin
          InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, Buffer, BuffSize, BytesRead);
          if BytesRead>0 then
          begin
            SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(Buffer), BytesRead);
            i:=Pos(TitleTagBegin,Result);
            if i>0 then
            begin
              f:=PosEx(TitleTagEnd,Result,i+Length(TitleTagBegin));
              Result:=Copy(Result,i+Length(TitleTagBegin),f-i-Length(TitleTagBegin));
            end;
          end;
        end;
       finally
         InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
       end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Buffer);
    end;
    InternetCloseHandle(hInter);
  end
end;

begin
  try
     Writeln(GetHTMLTitle('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966888/how-to-get-website-title-from-delphi'));
     Writeln(GetHTMLTitle('http://www.google.com/'));
     Writeln(GetHTMLTitle('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi'));
     Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Simple searching with Pos(Ex) might return wrong results, e.g. if the title tag is commented out.

Comment: +1 The native Windows API. "Me likes". (Although the `InternetCloseHandle` should probably be enclosed inside `finally` blocks, right?)

Comment: Beware of making assumptions about what sites/pages you can get to. Just because the user can get into their facebook, gmail, wallstreetjournal, etc., doesn't mean that you can do it too, without authentication.

Comment: @TOndrej, i agree with you about your comments using the Pos(Ex) function, i think which the only way to get more reliable results is using a `HTML parser`, this is just a basic sample ;).

Comment: @Andreas,you are right about your observation, the code was edited adding a `try..finally..end`

Comment: @Chris: that is another reason for using a TWebBrowser (or encapsulation of another web-browser like firefox or chrome). Hence my answer :-)

Answer (score 6):

It totally depends on how the web-site sets the title.

The `<title>` tag is not the only way, you also have JavaScript, etc.

The best is to encapsulate the page in a web-browser (For instance the `TWebBrowser`), then grab the title from there.

[This page](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/twebbrowser_oleobject.htm) has some leads on that.

--jeroen

Comment: Thx. Scripting on web pages is the trend, like it or not.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing with the idea of birger and making the code similar to RRUZ, using Indy (the component TidHTTP) the same routine can see similar to this:

```
function GetHTMLTitle(const Url:string):string;
const
  TitleTagBegin='<title>';
  TitleTagEnd  ='</title>';
var
  idH:TidHTTP;
  i,f:integer;
begin
  idH := TidHTTP.Create();
  try
    Result := idH.Get(Trim(URL));

    // Search theTAGS
    i:=Pos(TitleTagBegin,Result);
    if i>0 then begin
      f:=PosEx(TitleTagEnd,Result,i+Length(TitleTagBegin));
      Result:=Copy(Result,i+Length(TitleTagBegin),f-i-Length(TitleTagBegin));
    end;
  finally
    IdH.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Regards

Comment: Can't get this <title class="notranslate">Title</title>

Answer (score 1):

I have a parser (ATagParser) that makes this kind of thing trivial. It was a commercial product, but I took it off the market several years ago. I still actively use it and develop it and will send it to anyone that asks. It can be used for personal or commercial use as long as credit is given.

BTW, the idea of finding the  tags with POS is all well and good, but it will  miss title tags with attributes -- and yes, title tags can have attributes (dir, lang etc..)

would fail in the other options given.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Indy TIdHTTP component and use the same approach as RRUZ in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function below can also detect titles like that

```
<title class="notranslate">Title</title>
```

Here is the function:

```
function GetHTMLTitle(const HTML:string):string;
var
  tagstart: int64;
  tagstop: int64;
  titlestop: int64;
  temp:string;
  titletext: string;
begin
  Result:='';
  tagstart:=pos('<title',lowercase(html));
  if tagstart>0 then
  begin
    temp:=copy(html,tagstart);
    tagstop:=pos('>',temp);
    if tagstop>0 then
    begin
      temp:=copy(temp,tagstop+1);
      titlestop:=pos('</title>',lowercase(temp));
      if titlestop>0 then
      begin
        titletext:=copy(temp,1,titlestop-1);
        Result:=titletext;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```